Angular Material Expansion panel on focus arrow indicator should be underline
Angular Material Expansion panel on focus arrow indicator should be underline. this is requirement for accessibility (when focus on tab)
On accordions toggle when focus arrow indicator (up or down both) should be underline. How to do this? as shown in screenshot in red color



import {ChangeDetectionStrategy, Component, signal} from '@angular/core';
import {MatExpansionModule} from '@angular/material/expansion';

/**
 * @title Basic expansion panel
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'expansion-overview-example',
  templateUrl: 'expansion-overview-example.html',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [MatExpansionModule],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
export class ExpansionOverviewExample {
  readonly panelOpenState = signal(false);
}
<mat-accordion>
  <mat-expansion-panel hideToggle>
    <mat-expansion-panel-header>
      <mat-panel-title> This is the expansion title </mat-panel-title>
      <mat-panel-description> This is a summary of the content </mat-panel-description>
    </mat-expansion-panel-header>
    <p>This is the primary content of the panel.</p>
  </mat-expansion-panel>
  <mat-expansion-panel (opened)="panelOpenState.set(true)" (closed)="panelOpenState.set(false)">
    <mat-expansion-panel-header>
      <mat-panel-title> Self aware panel </mat-panel-title>
      <mat-panel-description>
        Currently I am {{panelOpenState() ? 'open' : 'closed'}}
      </mat-panel-description>
    </mat-expansion-panel-header>
    <p>I'm visible because I am open</p>
  </mat-expansion-panel>
</mat-accordion>




I have improved @naren-murali's answer. I think this implementation is what you need.
.custom-hover
  .mat-expansion-panel:not(:has(.mat-content-hide-toggle)):hover
  .mat-expansion-panel-header::after,
.custom-hover
  .mat-expansion-panel:not(:has(.mat-content-hide-toggle))
  .mat-expansion-panel-header:focus::after {
  background-color: red;
  content: '';
  display: inline;
  width: 16px;
  height: 2px;
  margin: 15px -4px 0 -12px;
}

https://stackblitz.com/edit/p4jjwk-hkndbv?embed=1&file=src%2Fstyles.scss&view=preview

working fine. Thanks!

You can use the below CSS, we simply add border-bottom to create the hover underline and apply it on hover.
.custom-hover span.mat-expansion-indicator {
  width: 15px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.custom-hover span.mat-expansion-indicator:hover {
  border-bottom: 3px solid red;
}

.custom-hover .mat-expansion-panel-header:focus span.mat-expansion-indicator {
  border-bottom: 3px solid red;
}

Stackblitz Demo

On hover arrow it's working stack blitz example but I need on hover and on tab focus on whole expansion div, could you plz review again

@arun use this same method, you should use :focus and add it, you can use inspect element to find the class to apply the styles on

hover working but :focus not working, could you plz try your end  code is .custom-hover:hover {
span.mat-expansion-indicator {
border-bottom: 3px solid red;
}
}
.custom-hover:focus {
span.mat-expansion-indicator {
border-bottom: 3px solid red;
}
}

@arun updated my answer

I checked stack blitz but still not working .custom-hover span.mat-expansion-indicator:hover {
border-bottom: 3px solid red;
}
.custom-hover .mat-expansion-panel-header:focus span.mat-expansion-indicator {
border-bottom: 3px solid red;
}

@arun require explanation of what is not working, more detailed the better

Focus code is not working i.e. mat-expansion-panel-header:focus span.mat-expansion-indicator { border-bottom: 3px solid red; } while hover is working
